# Trello Rest API to get all Trello cards which user is able to View/Edit/Delete using Trello website

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

I have a requirement that to display all Trello cards for which user has permission to view/edit/delete. I have gone through [Trello Rest API Documentation](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#membersidcards) and found below API to get the Trello cards.

```
https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/cards?key=AppKey&token=AccessToken
```

But when I used this API, it returned the empty list though the user is admin/member for all boards and each board has few lists and cards. Then I have directly added same user as a member to one of the Trello card and executed the same API. This time it has returned the card to which I added user as member.

But I don't want to add user as a member to each card. As user is already admin/member of all boards I would like show all cards of all boards irrespective of whether user is a member of card or not. Is there any Trello rest API exists to fetch all cards for which user has permission to view/edit/delete?

Any suggestions/answers are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got below response from Trello community.

You need to iterate through the boards. First, get the boards for the member:

`GET https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN`

Then, for each board in the array:

`GET https://api.trello.com/1/boards/BOARD_ID/cards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN`

It actually leads to multiple API calls: one to get the member's boards and one for each board.

Further, each board may contain more cards than can be returned in one request. A request typically only returns up to 1000 cards. If you want to get all the cards for each board, you may need to perform multiple requests per board, using the **before** parameter (you can find it in the documentation).

There is no way to obtain all the cards for all boards in one single request, as this would potentially cause a tremendous amount of data to be transferred.

[Trello community reference link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Trello-Rest-API-to-get-all-Trello-cards-which-user-is-able-to/qaq-p/675426#M2566)